# Vaadin 24 Details component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

After upgrade to Vaadin 24 I noticed that the text part of the Details component is not reacting on mouse click. Now to expand/collapse I have to use the toggle button only.

[image]

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/details

Is it possible to make the Details component work as it does in Vaadin 23?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, better reported to the web-components repo of Vaadin on Github.

Comment: done https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/5649